# IOS - AIR - Strange component appearing when rotating

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, rotation, components

We're developing an app for iOS using Adobe AIR. When rotating on an iOS device, a strange gray rectangle appears in the screen during the rotation and disappears after the rotation is complete.

This problem only occurs when I try to rotate it upside down to left and left to upside down.

I tested the application on multiples iPads and Android devices, and only iOS devices has this problem.

Has anyone seen this before?

[image]